# Youtube API 'nextPageToken' breaks when 'using order=relevance'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, youtube-data-api

I am using python 3 to paginate through all comments in a video.
Let's say that the video, selected at random, has the id `GFphNr0FK-0`. As of now, there are 5450 comments.

I am paging through the results retrieved and checking if there is a `nextPageToken` key present. If there is, I grab the value from it and continue to loop until that key is no longer present.

With each iteration or `page`, I append the comments to a list. I get to 1600 comments (16 pages, 100 comments per page) and then I start getting error 400's.

When I inspect the `nextPageToken`, I see that with every request it gets longer and longer... I am not appending anything to it and it is literally retrieved using `page_info['nextPageToken']`.

For clarity, this is my paging:

```
self.COMMENT_URL_PAGED = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&maxResults=100&order=relevance&videoId={videoId}&key={key}'

if 'nextPageToken' not in page_info:
    run = False
else:
    next_page_token = page_info['nextPageToken']

while run:

    page_info = requests.get(self.COMMENT_URL_PAGED.format(videoId = video_id, key = self.KEY, pageToken = next_page_token))

    while page_info.status_code != 200:
        time.sleep(10)
        page_info = requests.get(self.COMMENT_URL_PAGED.format(videoId = video_id, key = self.KEY, pageToken = next_page_token))
        print('Something went wrong. Token is: {}'.format(next_page_token))

    page_info = page_info.json()

    for i in range(len(page_info['items'])):
        comments.append(page_info['items'][i]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'])

    if 'nextPageToken' not in page_info:
        run = False
        next_page_token = None
    else:
        next_page_token = page_info['nextPageToken']
```

Anything obviously incorrect?

**UPDATE**

So, I have found that if I remove the `order` querystring parameter, it works as expected....

Why would `&order=relevance` cause it to break after 16 pages??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question, it might be the solution to my problem.

Same problem, with only difference, that response winds up `200 OK`, with empty `items`.